# Problem with "@UserName" not appearing in comments

Tags: discussion, bug

I searched for this topic but couldn't find any.

Why is it that sometimes you can't direct a comment to a user? When typing "@Use" I would expect that "UserName" pops up as a tooltip shortcut, but sometimes it doesn't. And when it doesn't it doesn't either keep the @UserName when I submit the comment.

What is the reasoning behind this? Is it a ubiquitous bug that just hasn't gotten any attention, or is it a feature that I just haven't been able to appreciate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are responding to the person who asked the question (in a comment on a question) or who answered the question (in a comment on an answer) and there aren't any comments by other people, then Stack Exchange doesn't allow putting the username in, because it knows your comment is directed to the original poster automatically. This has been discussed multiple times on meta.stackexchange.com and even though it is confusing the SE folks think it is better than the way it used to be for some reason.

Comment: hmmm... so there is logic behind it after all. I can't say I like it, and sounds to me like you agree. Very well, hopefully they decide to remove this filter. I mean, once more people are involved it could get a bit confusing following up which comments are answers to other comments from when there only were two discussing. Very well, thank you Charles!